# Prestashop 1.6 - use my custom content.tpl in adminController

Tags: php, templates, overriding, customization, prestashop

I defined my content.tpl template in my module, so i want to use it in my admin controller that i extended from prestashop AdminController.

I know there is a property in which i can set the path to my template, but i don't know how to define the right path to it because when i execute the code prestashop add `

```
'C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\admin0559umpxx/themes/default\template\`
```

To my link.

My custom template located in mymodule/views/templates/admin/content.tpl, and the property i use to set my path is $this->template.

indeed, my code is like this :

```
class AdminSelStockController extends AdminController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->module = new SelStock();

        $this->addRowAction('edit'); //add an edit button
        $this->addRowAction('delete'); //add a delete button
        $this->bulk_actions = array('delete' => array('text' => $this->l('Delete selected'), 'confirm' => $this->l('Delete selected items?')));
        $this->explicitSelect = true;
        $this->context = Context::getContext();
        $this->id_lang = $this->context->language->id;
        $this->path = _MODULE_DIR_."selStock";

        $this->default_form_language = $this->context->language->id;
        $this->table = 'selstock_product'; //define the main table
        $this->className = 'SelStockProductModel'; //define the module entity
        $this->identifier = "id_selstock_product"; //the primary key
        //then define select part of the query
        $this->_select = 'a.id_selstock_product,a.image_path,a.reference,a.product_name,a.category_name,a.quatity';
        //join to an existing table if you need some extra informations
        $this->_join = 'LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'selstock_product_lang` spl ON (spl.`id_selstock_product` = a.`id_selstock_product`)';
        $this->_where = "AND spl.id_lang = '".$this->id_lang."'";
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        $this->layout = _PS_MODULE_DIR_.'/selStock/views/templates/admin/layout.tpl';
        $this->template = _PS_MODULE_DIR_.'/selStock/views/templates/admin/content.tpl';
        //and define the field to display in the admin table
        $this->fields_list = array(
            'id_selstock_product' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Product Num'),
                'align' => 'center',
                'width' => 120
            ),
            'image_path' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Image'),
                'align' => 'center',
                'width' => 120
            ),
            'reference' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Reference'),
                'align' => 'center',
                'width' => 120
            ),
            'product_name' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Name'),
                'align' => 'center',
                'width' => 120
            ),
            'category_name' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Category'),
                'align' => 'center',
                'width' => 120
            ),
            'quatity' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Quantity'),
                'align' => 'center',
                'width' => 120
            ),
            'store_name' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Store'),
                'align' => 'center',
                'width' => 120
            )
        );

        parent::__construct();
    }
```

For layout it's ok, i could use my own.but i don't know where is the problem with template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very cool, i found the solution by adding these functions to my adminController :

```
/**
     * Get path to back office templates for the module
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTemplatePath()
    {
        return _PS_MODULE_DIR_.$this->module->name.'/views/templates/admin/';
    }

    public function createTemplate($tpl_name) {
        if (file_exists($this->getTemplatePath() . $tpl_name) && $this->viewAccess())
            return $this->context->smarty->createTemplate($this->getTemplatePath() . $tpl_name, $this->context->smarty);
            return parent::createTemplate($tpl_name);
    }

    public function initContent(){
        parent::initContent();
        $tpl = $this->createTemplate('content.tpl')->fetch();
        /* DO STUFF HERE */
//        $posts = array();

//        $this->context->smarty->assign('posts', $posts);

    }
```

Comment: I must wait two days after my post to mark it answered

Answer (score 1):

You should extend your class with ModuleAdminController not AdminController